# How could I receive UDP packets from in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, browser, udp

Part of a system I'm currently writing involves sending data from an Android phone to a desktop computer using UDP packets. The Android component creates a DatagramPacket that is sent using a DatagramSocket. The DatagramPacket specifies the InetAddress as the local IP of the desktop, and uses an unreserved port (currently 5000).

I have also decided that the desktop portion of this system should run in a web browser in order to maintain cross-platform compatability.

What are my options when it comes to implementing a mechanism for receiving the UDP packets on the desktop client? I'm ideally looking for a purely client-side approach that doesn't require a connection to the Android device or to a remote server.

If building this for a web browser isn't feasible, I'm more than happy to try alternative approaches.

Comment: Web browsers use HTTP/HTTPS, which runs on top of TCP.

Comment: ...And they shouldn't be able to receive UPD packets.